# Resize Dropdown menu

Tags: html, css

I am trying to resize dropdown menu, where I have text+picture. But the border is making part of the menu bigger, and that's the issue. I need to have text and under the text the picture of product. Is there any way to do it by css?

HTML

```
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="header">
      <img src="./images.png" class="image" alt="logo" />
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Menu</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Roofs<img src="https://insta-galery.w3spaces.com/strecha.jpg"/></a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: 1px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.image{
  display: flex;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 1px 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: flex;}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #3e8e41;}
```

Comment: the picture is under the text. so what's the issue? explain more or share a picture that shows your desired result

Comment: @Mad7Dragon Here is the picture -> https://ibb.co/z2hjRKN 
All I need the picture to move under the text and make the white space in this box smaller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed this:

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: flex;}
```

`display: flex` to `block`. It solved  my problem.